# Delete DB and transaction logs on Neo4j 4.2.3 Community Server

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to automate some data import into neo4j (Community Server) as follows: on a daily basis, I need the data to be deleted and new data to be imported.
In previous versions of neo4j,(3.x) I was able to perform db data deletion by using the following command
`echo "$(cat /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf| sed -n 's/.*dbms.directories.data=//p')"/databases/"$(cat /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf | sed -n 's/.*dbms.active_database=//p')"/* | xargs rm -rf`

Now, when I am running the same command, it appears that the db is deleted, but the transaction logs are not, hence neo4j cannot start.

```
Directories in use:
  home:         /var/lib/neo4j
  config:       /etc/neo4j
  logs:         /var/log/neo4j
  plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
  import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
  data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
  certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
  run:          /var/run/neo4j
Starting Neo4j.
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4                                                                                                                                                             j manual.
2021-02-11 21:45:22.869+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-02-11 21:45:24.342+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.2.3 ========
2021-02-11 21:45:32.737+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on dbms.connector.http.listen_address, a socket address. If missing port or hostname it is acquired from dbms.default_listen_address.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting Neo4j database server at /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:207) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:163) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:36) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:134) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:90) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:35) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultSystemGraphInitializer@5634a861' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Fail to start 'DatabaseId{00000000[system]}' since transaction logs were found, while database files are missing.".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:463) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:198) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize system graph component: This database is shutdown.
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.SystemGraphComponents.initializeSystemGraph(SystemGraphComponents.java:102) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultSystemGraphInitializer.initializeSystemGraph(DefaultSystemGraphInitializer.java:41) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.SystemGraphInitializer.start(SystemGraphInitializer.java:29) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:442) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:198) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.DatabaseShutdownException: This database is shutdown.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.availability.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard.assertDatabaseAvailable(DatabaseAvailabilityGuard.java:172) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginKernelTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:197) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransactionInternal(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:176) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:122) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:116) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:104) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTx(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:99) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractSystemGraphComponent.detect(AbstractSystemGraphComponent.java:118) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractSystemGraphComponent.initializeSystemGraph(AbstractSystemGraphComponent.java:93) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.SystemGraphComponents.initializeSystemGraph(SystemGraphComponents.java:92) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultSystemGraphInitializer.initializeSystemGraph(DefaultSystemGraphInitializer.java:41) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.SystemGraphInitializer.start(SystemGraphInitializer.java:29) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:442) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:198) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        ... 5 more
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.graphdb.DatabaseShutdownException: This database is shutdown.
                at org.neo4j.kernel.availability.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard.assertDatabaseAvailable(DatabaseAvailabilityGuard.java:172) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginKernelTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:197) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransactionInternal(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:176) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:122) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:116) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:104) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTx(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:99) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractSystemGraphComponent.detect(AbstractSystemGraphComponent.java:118) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractSystemGraphComponent.initializeSystemGraph(AbstractSystemGraphComponent.java:93) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.SystemGraphComponents.initializeSystemGraph(SystemGraphComponents.java:92) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultSystemGraphInitializer.initializeSystemGraph(DefaultSystemGraphInitializer.java:41) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.SystemGraphInitializer.start(SystemGraphInitializer.java:29) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:442) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:198) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:163) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:36) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:134) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:90) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:35) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to start 'DatabaseId{00000000[system]}' since transaction logs were found, while database files are missing.
                at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.validateLogsAndStoreAbsence(Database.java:546) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.validateStoreAndTxLogs(Database.java:538) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.start(Database.java:419) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.startDatabase(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:187) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultDatabaseManager.startDatabase(DefaultDatabaseManager.java:152) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultDatabaseManager.startDatabase(DefaultDatabaseManager.java:36) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.forEachDatabase(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:165) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.startAllDatabases(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:112) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.start(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:106) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                ... 8 more
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.graphdb.DatabaseShutdownException: This database is shutdown.
                at org.neo4j.kernel.availability.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard.assertDatabaseAvailable(DatabaseAvailabilityGuard.java:172) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginKernelTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:197) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransactionInternal(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:176) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:122) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:116) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:104) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTx(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:99) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractSystemGraphComponent.detect(AbstractSystemGraphComponent.java:118) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractSystemGraphComponent.initializeSystemGraph(AbstractSystemGraphComponent.java:93) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.SystemGraphComponents.initializeSystemGraph(SystemGraphComponents.java:92) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultSystemGraphInitializer.initializeSystemGraph(DefaultSystemGraphInitializer.java:41) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.SystemGraphInitializer.start(SystemGraphInitializer.java:29) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:442) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:198) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:163) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:36) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:134) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:90) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:35) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to start 'DatabaseId{00000000[system]}' since transaction logs were found, while database files are missing.
                at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.validateLogsAndStoreAbsence(Database.java:546) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.validateStoreAndTxLogs(Database.java:538) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.start(Database.java:419) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.startDatabase(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:187) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultDatabaseManager.startDatabase(DefaultDatabaseManager.java:152) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultDatabaseManager.startDatabase(DefaultDatabaseManager.java:36) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.forEachDatabase(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:165) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.startAllDatabases(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:112) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.start(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:106) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
                ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to start 'DatabaseId{00000000[system]}' since transaction logs were found, while database files are missing.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.validateLogsAndStoreAbsence(Database.java:546) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.validateStoreAndTxLogs(Database.java:538) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.start(Database.java:419) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.startDatabase(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:187) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultDatabaseManager.startDatabase(DefaultDatabaseManager.java:152) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DefaultDatabaseManager.startDatabase(DefaultDatabaseManager.java:36) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.forEachDatabase(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:165) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.startAllDatabases(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:112) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.dbms.database.AbstractDatabaseManager.start(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:106) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:442) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:198) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        ... 5 more
2021-02-11 21:45:32.746+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

Any clues into what to do? Manually deleting the entire content of the data folder does not quite help, as the authentification to the db, in order to allow the import is no longer working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Neo4j 4+, you will need to delete:

```
/data/databases/<your_db_name>
/data/transactions/<your_db_name>
```